# IIS ConnectionTimeout applies to exactly what operation?

Tags: asp.net, connection, iis-7.5, config, connection-timeout

IIS 7.5.7600.16385

What exactly does the IIS metabase setting connectionTimeout apply to ?

- time to establish connection
- time to receive complete request ( including large request body sent with 100-continue headers )
- time for back-end service/site to send response

Specifically, for an ASP.NET MVC Web API RESTful service with an endpoint that performs long-running batch operations ( say 10 mins ) do I need to adjust IIS ConnectionTimeout config setting to a much higher value than the default 120 secs ?